# Adding an extra class in a referenced assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Not sure if this is possible, so I am referencing a dll in my project.I would like to add another class in the dll and then reference he same in my project.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: ..do you have access to the code that comprises this assembly?

Comment: If you don't have the source, you'd need to wrap the the assembly and add your class to the wrapper.

Comment: Apart from Simon's comment, is there any need for you to actually do this? You could always create your own dll, wrapper classes, extension methods...

Comment: There are safe ways round it, create your own dll, that uses the original one, or get the source, chnage it and compile your own version of the dll, (given you aren't breaking the licence terms)but in terms of the apparent intent of your question, no, absolutely not. The ability to do so would be fragile, insecure unsafe and potentially theft.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I do have the code for the dll

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: As mentioned before I do have the source code but i didn't want to modify the same. I thought there might be a way using reflection

Comment: @Sayse: Wanted to keep the original dll same. Not sure if I would be able to create wrapper classes, the assmebly has some styles in XAML also.

Comment: Are you sure your not just looking for how to change the version number of your dll? There is no possible way to change something/anything and keep it the same

Comment: @Sayse : No no, not the version number. I want to add another class in the assembly which uses some of the components of the assembly. Then I want to use the newly created class in the assembly in my project

Answer (score 0):

For this change you should have a solution which is generating your DLL than you add a class to that solution and compile it again and use the reference of the DLL in your  project.